# How do I run cmd full function

Tags: c#

problem in cmd.exe while i open it from c#
..
when i open start > run > cmd
and write this command ..
c:>msg \server:"192.168.6.5" * "send hello " 
the obove command executed correctly
but 
when i run cmd from c#.net this command get this error

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Process.Start("cmd.exe");

            }
```

and then write the same command
c:>msg \server:"192.168.6.5" * "send hello "
output message : **msg is not recognized as an internal or external command...**

what's the problem ??
plz help

Comment: Where are you specifying the command line arguments?

Comment: the command should be msg \server:"192.168.6.5" * "send hello "

Comment: methinks you need setup [WorkingDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

1) If you're on 64 bit, you may have to use "C:\windows\sysnative\msg.exe". Or use System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable to get the path and then pass it in to a new ProcessStartInfo object. e.g.

```
 string path = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
 // add in the extra path parts if required

 ProcessStartInfo pinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

 pinfo.WorkingDirectory = "whatever";
 pinfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";
 pinfo.Arguments = "whatever";
 pinfo.EnvironmentVariables["Path"] = path;
```

Then pass that into Process.Start

2) Also, from the documentation "The user must have send message access permission to send a message.", so it will depend on what privileges you're running the process under.

Comment: yes  64 bit .. i try your code but need to add this line .. pinfo.UseShellExecute = false  ;.... but also the same problem occured 
 i still need a solution

Comment: how to execute this command ><pre>msg \server:"192.168.6.5" * "send hello "</pre> 
using c#